# Passing the value from a column of a table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using these table examples:

**Table1**

```
Barcode
0000001
0000002
0000003
0000004
0000005
```

**Table2**

```
Barcode | Description
0000001      DescA
0000002      DescB
0000003      DescC
0000004      DescD
0000005      DescE
0000006      DescF
0000007      DescG
0000008      DescH
```

Is there a way to pass the values of `Barcode` in `Table1` to be used in `Table2` to get the relevant `Description`?

I tried using this:

```
SELECT Barcode, (SELECT Description FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE Barcode = dbo.Table1.Barcode)
FROM dbo.Table1
```

Unfortunately, it returned an error after display some results for a short time

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I think my query is close enough, but I can't pass the result of `Barcode` to be passed to the other query to get the `Description` per run

I don't really know the search terms to be used so I can't find some answers or tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use some inner join statement like:

```
SELECT table1.Barcode,table2.Description
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.barcode = table2.barcode
```